# Ranking numbers in lines in a text file from biggest to least?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a text file that looks like:

```
Josh123: Level 2
Marcus N: Level 4
Callie [L16]: Level 1
Ashley 4: Level 3
```

What I want is that it will sort each of them by their levels and print it, so like:

```
Marcus N: Level 4
Ashley 4: Level 3
Josh123: Level 2
Callie [L16]: Level 1
```

Is there a way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: You should provide example code of what you tried. Read the rules about posting questions. Edit with your tried and your particular doubt.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways. Here's one simple one:

```
with open("myFile") as lines:
    print(''.join(reversed(sorted(lines, key = lambda line:int(line.split()[-1])))))
```

A slightly more robust way:

```
import re
def getLevel(line):
    match = re.search('Level ([0-9]+)', line)
    if match:
        return int(match.groups()[0])
    return 0

with open("myFile") as lines:
    print(''.join(reversed(sorted(lines, key = getLevel))))
```

This will put lines that don't match "Level N" at the end. Replace `return 0` with `return 9999` or the like to put them at the beginning.

Also see [Thomas Howard's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48329132/9200529) for a nice alternative.

Comment: This shows the lowest levels first, how do I make it go from greatest to least and not least to greatest?

Comment: It says invalid syntax so I changed it to `print(''.join(reversed(lines, key = lambda line:int(line.split()[-1]))))` and it now says `TypeError: reversed() does not take keyword arguments`

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I lost a parenthesis in an edit. I've fixed the answer. Instead of what you have in your comment, you need `print(''.join(reversed(sorted(lines, key = lambda line:int(line.split()[-1])))))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
with open('filename.txt') as f:
  data = [i.strip('\n') for i in f]
final_data = '\n'.join(map(lambda x:x[0], sorted(zip(data, [int(re.findall('(?<=Level\s)\d+', i)[0]) for i in data]), key=lambda x:x[-1], reverse=True)))
```

Output:

```
Marcus N: Level 4
Ashley 4: Level 3
Josh123: Level 2
Callie [L16]: Level 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go for

```
import re

string = """
Josh123: Level 2
Marcus N: Level 4
Callie [L16]: Level 1
Ashley 4: Level 3
"""

rx = re.compile(r'.+Level (\d+)')

# create the list of tuples and sort em
sorted_students = sorted([(match.group(0), int(match.group(1))) 
        for match in rx.finditer(string)], 
        key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)

# join the first item of every tuple with \n
student = "\n".join(student[0] for student in sorted_students)
print(student)
```

Which yields

```
Marcus N: Level 4
Ashley 4: Level 3
Josh123: Level 2
Callie [L16]: Level 1
```

---

The idea here is match every line with `Level [some digits here]`, convert the digit and sort by this one afterwards. In the end, join the result with `\n` back again.

Answer (score 0):

Another, slightly more robust way, would be to actually build user objects, store them in a list, then sort that. It's extensible, if you add other fields, you can easily build out the namedtuples:

```py
""" Sort players by level

Read a text file, each line represents a user.
Sort these users by level in reversed order.
"""
import re
from collections import namedtuple

User = namedtuple('User', ['level', 'info']) # Named tuple stores user information.
LEVEL_PATTERN = re.compile(r'Level (?P<level>\d+)$') # This finds the users level, compiled only once.

users = [] # A place to hold the users

# Read players in
with open('players.txt') as players:
    for player in players:
        level = re.search(LEVEL_PATTERN, player).group('level')
        users.append(User(level, (player.strip())))

# Sort, and print
for player in sorted(users, key=lambda player: int(player.level), reverse=True): # timeit 2.88, n=1000
    print(player.info)
```

Best

---

Edited to use dot-notation and numeric sorting instead of lexicographical.

---

Also note, the int() part of this snippet can be moved. For example, it can be placed when level is first saved, instead of in the lambda expression:

```
for player in players:
    level = int(re.search(LEVEL_PATTERN, player).group('level'))
    users.append(User(level, (player.strip())))
```

Or, when the `nampedtuple` is created:

```
level = re.search(LEVEL_PATTERN, player).group('level')
users.append(User(int(level), (player.strip()))) # tiemit 2.06, n=1000
```

Theoretically, and practically, the above method is faster. On my limited sample it was ~0.8 faster per loop according to timeit.

This makes sense, because doing conversions during comparison can lead to more conversions than if they are done on intake. Taking more time per comparison during the sorting process.

Further, since no sorting algorithm achieves O(n), conversion on intake is the better approach.

Comment: This is nice, but it will sort levels in lex order rather than numeric order, which probably isn't what they're after.

Comment: Also if you're using a named tuple you might as well use `player.info` instead of `player[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
>>> print(txt)
Josh123: Level 2
Marcus N: Level 4
Callie [L16]: Level 1
Ashley 4: Level 3
```

You can do:

```
>>> sorted(txt.splitlines(), key=lambda line: -int(line.split()[-1]))
['Marcus N: Level 4', 'Ashley 4: Level 3', 'Josh123: Level 2', 'Callie [L16]: Level 1']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like:

```
map_data={}
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        map_data[line.split(':')[1].strip().split()[1]]=line.strip()

print(list(map(lambda x:map_data[x],sorted(map_data,reverse=True))))
```

output:

```
['Marcus N: Level 4', 'Ashley 4: Level 3', 'Josh123: Level 2', 'Callie [L16]: Level 1']
```